# Using ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND to add function that copies files

Tags: xilinx, yocto, openembedded, petalinux

What I used to do this was use `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` variable to add my own shell script functions.
I needed to append the petalinux-user-image in `meta-plnx-generated` so in my `meta-user` layer, I created the following file: petalinux-user-image.bbappend:

```
inherit core-image

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "my_install_function; "


my_install_function(){
    echo "hello" > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/hello.txt
}
```

What I am trouble with is how do I add files to the `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}`. I can remove/move files/create files, but can't seem to copy files from my `meta-user` layer to the `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}`, like with normal recipes where I can install files. The `${WORKDIR}` points the rootfs folders in build, and `${THIS_DIR}` seems to point to the petalinux-user-image in `meta-plnx-generated`. I have given the `meta-user` layer a higher priority than the `meta-plnx-generated` layer, so task order is correct.

Help or ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is that you're doing this backwards.  The best practice here would be to write recipes for the additional files you want in your image and include those packages in your image.  The ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND hook is intended for minor content tweaks.

Comment: I moved the extra addition of files to my own recipe which 'installs' the files. I then use the ROOTFS_POSPROCESS_COMMAND simply for creating out of place symlinks, and as you say, minor tweaks.